# BB java objectchoicefiled should get display autmatically on selecting one value in other objectchoicefield i.e onchange functionality

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Hi am trying to display objectchoicefield by set of data in array.by selecting that comparing with other array automatically another objectchoicefield should get display with corresponding matches.i.e, onchange function, the other objectchoicefield should get load with values.guide me.

```java
Document document=generalXmlAccess.access(generalXmlAccess.getArea());
NodeList list2=document.getElementsByTagName("tuple");  
final String[] area = new String [list2.getLength()];
final String[] areaid = new String [list2.getLength()];

for(int i=0;i<list2.getLength();i++) 
{
    NodeList list=document.getElementsByTagName("NAME");  
    NodeList list3=document.getElementsByTagName("ROW_ID"); 
    area[i]=list.item(i).getFirstChild().toString()+"-"+list3.item(i).getFirstChild().toString(); 
    areaid[i]=list3.item(i).getFirstChild().toString(); 
}

final ObjectChoiceField choiceField=new ObjectChoiceField("Select Area",area);    
choiceField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    if(field.equals(choiceField))
    {
            int index=choiceField.getSelectedIndex();
            String values=areaid[index].toString(); 
            Document document1=generalXmlAccess.access(generalXmlAccess.getSubArea());
            NodeList list3=document1.getElementsByTagName("tuple");   
            for(int i=0;i<list3.getLength();i++)
            {
                subareaid=new String[list3.getLength()]; 
                NodeList nodeList=document1.getElementsByTagName("PAR_ROW_ID"); 
                if(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().toString().equals(values))
                {
                    NodeList list=document1.getElementsByTagName("NAME");
                    subareaid[i]=list.item(i).getFirstChild().toString();
                }
                add(new ObjectChoiceField("Subarea", subareaid)); 
            }
    }
}
});

choiceField.setFont(font1);
```

Comment: create a custom dropdown, then implement its field change lstener event.

Comment: pls go through my code and guide me

Comment: may i know why somebody de-voted for me.wats the problem with my question?

Answer (score 1):

I think, following steps might guide you.

**Step 1:** Create first `objectchoicefield` with its data.

**Step 2:** Implement its field change listener, in which you will use the selected value of first `choicefield` as parameter to get the array of corresponding values to be set to second `objectchoicefield` ..

Comment: ya like that only i have done .but is not working for me.pls check the code i have updated at top.